# Pregunta sobre variables static

Tags: java

leyendo el libro de "Como programar en java de paul deitel", dice lo siguiente sobre variables static: "En la sección 3.2 vimos que cada objeto de una clase mantiene su propia copia de cada variable de instancia de la clase. Hay variables para las que cada objeto de una clase no necesita su propia copia independiente (como veremos en breve). Dichas variables se declaran como static y también se conocen como variables
de clase. Cuando se crean los objetos de una clase que contiene variables static , todos los objetos de esa clase comparten una copia de esas variables. En conjunto, las variables static y las variables de instancia de una clase se conocen como sus campos. En la sección 8.11 aprenderá más sobre los campos static ."

Cuando dicen esto: "Cuando se crean los objetos de una clase que contiene variables static , todos los objetos de esa clase comparten una copia de esas variables." ¿que quieren decir ellos? con "Todos los objetos de esa clase comparte una copia de esas variables", significa que, N objetos creados de esa clase ven el mismo contenido de esa variable "static" y por ende digamos que están conectados(no se si es correcta la aseveración), o que cada objeto tiene su propia copia, que solo ese objeto puede manipular¿? 
Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Una vez variable static, es única y la misma para todas las instancias creadas. Alguno casos en los cuales uso variables statics son: definición de constantes inherentes a la clase; con el uso de semáforos en determinados casos puede ser útil. También entiendo que no es necesario crear una instancia (siempre que la variable static sea pública) La variable static, al pertenecer a la clase y no a cada instancia se puede acceder sin necesidad de crear un objeto. Ejemplo, float numPI = MyClass.PI; y public class MyClass { public static float PI = 3.14;}

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ahora si entiendo mejor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las variable de instancia (nonstatic) se crean cuando se crea el objeto. Las variable static se crean cuando el classloader carga la clase.

**static = class, nonstatic = instance**

Por la misma razón a las variables estáticas se accede con `NombreClase.variable`. Si lo intentamos con `nombreInstancia.variable` el compilador genera *warning*. No es error pero nos avisa que el acceso a variables estáticas se debe hacer de forma estática.

Si la variable estática es pública todos acceden a la misma variable (todos los objetos desde fuera) y todos modifican la misma variable. Sin embargo si fuese variable de instancia todos que acceden desde fuera deberían crear una instancia del objeto y accederían a diferentes instancias de la variable al pertenecer estas a diferentes objetos.

¿Por qué tenemos un método `public static void main` en las clases? Para poder acceder a este método **sin** crear instancia del objeto. Si no fuese así ¿cómo podríamos ejecutar un programa?

Por la diferencia entre variables de instancia y estáticas surge la prohibición o imposibilidad de acceder a variables de instancia desde contexto estático.

```
class A {
    int x = 3;
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

No compila - no se puede acceder a `x` desde un contexto estático. La `x` pertenece a la instancia que todavía no se ha creado.

En general - todo lo que es estático, variables, métodos o clases (inner) es accesible sin crear instancia del objeto.

No se si esto aclara algo de tus dudas

Comment: Excelente respuesta, gracias!!!