# Bloques de Inicializacion en Java

Tags: java

```
package Ejercicios;

public class Swan {

    private String name = "Fluffy";

    {
        System.out.println("setting field");
    }

    public Swan() {
        name = "Tiny";
        System.out.println("setting constructor");
    }

    static {
        System.out.println("Static initalization.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Swan chick = new Swan();
        Swan chick2 = new Swan();
    }

}
```

Salida

```
Static initalization.
setting field
setting constructor
setting field
setting constructor
```

Estoy tratando de entender estos bloques de inicialización, pero no entiendo esta parte del static

¿Pórque solo imprime una vez el Static initalization?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Pregunta sobre variables static](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239679/pregunta-sobre-variables-static)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > ¿Pórque solo imprime una vez el Static initalization?

Porque el bloque estático solo se ejecutará cuando la clase `Swap` se cargue en memoria (toda clase de Java genera una instancia de tipo [Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)) y por esa razón imprime primero `Static initalization.`

En este caso dio este resultado porque la clase `Swap` era la principal (donde está el método `main`). Pero, ¿que pasaría si el bloque estático no está en la clase `Swap`, sino, en `Swap2`? Pues el bloque no se ejecutaría primero.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
class Swap2 
{
    static {
        System.out.println("Static initalization.");
    }
}

public class Swap {

    {
        System.out.println("setting field");
    }

    public Swap() {
        System.out.println("setting constructor");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Swap chick = new Swap();
        Swap2 chick2 = new Swap2();
        Swap2 chick3 = new Swap2();
    }
}
```

Resultado en pantalla:

```java
setting field
setting constructor
Static initalization.
```

En este caso después de asignar la dirección base del objeto a la variable `chick`, la clase `Swap2` se cargará en memoria y posteriormente se ejecuta el bloque estático.

Por más que creemos más de una instancia de tipo `Swap2`, el bloque estático solo se ejecutará una vez cuando la clase se cargue en memoria.

Answer (score 0):

Static es un atributo de clase, no de de instancia, por tanto solamente se usa una vez por clase, esta seria la explicación breve, tiene mas miga detrás si quieres saber de ello. Diríamos que "Static" convierte cualquier atributo en global para toda la clase y por ello solamente se ve una vez impreso aunque lo hayas instanciado dos.

Answer (score 0):

el static en este caso es única para toda la clase (ocupa un único lugar en memoria). Si no usarás static, el sistema crea un lugar nuevo para esa variable o constante o método con cada instancia (la variable es diferente para cada objeto).